# Show that the following sequence is bounded...

Tags: calculus

let L be the set of all real sequences ${a_n}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges absolutely.

now let ${a_n}$ be a sequence such that ${a_nb_n}$$\in$L for every ${b_n}$$\in$L show that ${a_n}$ is a bounded sequence.

Attemps:

I have tried to show that ${a_n}$ converges, in order to draw the conclusion that it must be bounded, so I tried to prove that it must be a cauchy sequence aswell as just computing limits by addition rules but I dont seem to make it. Im looking for some hints.

Comment: It need not converge, $a_n = (-1)^n$ for example satisfies the condition. Suppose you have an unbounded sequence $(c_n)$. Construct a sequence $(b_n)$ in $L$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert c_n b_n\rvert = +\infty.$$

Comment: Very useful comment, thanks. I might not approach to problem that way then. Do you have any hints on how i can prove this?

Comment: You start with an unbounded sequence $(c_n)$. Then you extract a subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ that grows (in absolute value) not too slowly. Then you choose a sequence $(b_n)$ in $L$ such that the termwise product of the two sequences is not (absolutely) convergent. You can set $b_n = 0$ if $n$ is none of the $n_k$, and $b_{n_k}$ can be chosen depending on $c_{n_k}$.